# How can I join two data that have different types of data?

Tags: r, left-join

Let's say I have two data.
one is like this:

```
names |height
------|------
"ab"  |176
------|--------
"aa"  |168
------|--------
"ac"  |189
------|--------
"ad"  |179
```

and the other is like this:

```
names           weight
c("aa","ab")    58
c("ac","ae")    70
"ad"            68
```

so the second names are list, but the first names are just vector.
I want to make like this:

```
names  height  weight
"ab"   176     58
"aa"   168     58
"ac"   189     70
"ad"   179     68
```

I tried to use left_join, but it didn't work.
And I also tried to make list to vector.
When I made list to vector, the problem is lengths are different each other.
Please, can you help me???
This is my first question on stackoverflow.

Add my code

```
names<-c("ab","aa","ac","ad")
height<-c(176,168,189,179)
data1<-cbind(names,height)
names<-list(c("aa","ab"),c("ac","ae"),"ad")
weight<-c(58,70,68)
data2<-cbind(names,weight)
data1<-as.data.frame(data1) ;data1;str(data1)
data2<-as.data.frame(data2) ;data2;str(data2)
data2 %>%
```

unnest %>%
  left_join(.,data1, by = "names")

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please share your code even if it didn't work.

Comment: ok, I will edit more with some code.

Comment: oh, it just automatically changed itself!!!!

Comment: You are creating a matrix with `cbind` and this will create more problems for you as matrix can take only a single class.  So it converts to numeric to character because there is character elements and then you need to go the reconversion etc..  Instead use `data1 <- data.frame(names, height)` and `data2 <- data.frame(names = I(names), weight)`

Comment: I really appreciate you!! thanks again!!

Comment: Could I ask one more question??
In the second data frame, if the first element have two names like example and the second element have three names unlike above example, then how could I work with that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` assuming that the 'names' column is a `list` in the second dataset.  With `unnest`, convert it to a `vector` and then `left_join` with the first dataset `by` 'names'

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>%
   unnest %>%
   left_join(df1, ., by = "names") 
#   names height weight
#1    ab    176     58
#2    aa    168     58
#3    ac    189     70
#4    ad    179     68
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(names = c("ab", "aa", "ac", "ad"),
  height = c(176, 168, 189, 179), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(names = I(list(c("aa", "ab"), c("ac", "ae"), "ad")),
  weight = c(58, 70, 68))
```

Comment: Could you explain more?? What is unnest??

Comment: @DosanHwang  I added some explanation `unnest` is a function from `tidyr` which is one of the packages that gets loaded with `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I get an error.
Error in UseMethod("unnest_") : 
  no applicable method for 'unnest_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'list')"
How should I do???

Comment: @DosanHwang  Looks like you have a `matrix` for `df2` convert it to a `data.frame` i..e  `df2 %>% as.data.frame %>% unnest` and check if that works

Comment: Now I get this error. Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.

Comment: @DosanHwang I assumed that you have a `list` column in 'df2' and df2 is a data.frame.  Could you please update your post with the `dput` of the example i.e. `dput(df2)`

Comment: @DosanHwang  I updated with the example I used.  It is giving the expected output as you showed